# How to calculate order total after check out

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have calculated a different custom order total in Woocommerce:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 );
function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
    // Get order total
    $total = $order->get_total();

    $orderproduct = $order->get_items();
    $tax_rate     = WC_Tax::get_rates( $orderproduct );

    if ($tax_rate == "10") {
        $percent10 = $total * $tax_rate; 
    }

    if ( $tax_rate == "4" ){
        $percent4 = $total * $tax_rate;
    }

    ## -- fai check e calcoli -- ##
    $new_total = $total + $percent4 + $percent10; // <== Fake calculation

    // imposta un calcolo nuovo
    $order->set_total( $new_total );
}
```

But my calculations don't work and I'm not able to make it for instance.

Any advice or help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there ever a time you would have both tax rates? Otherwise, I would think one variable for taxes would be enough, like so:

```
if ($tax_rate == "10") {
    $tax_total = $total * $tax_rate; 
}

if ( $tax_rate == "4" ){
    $tax_total = $total * $tax_rate;
}

## -- fai check e calcoli -- ##
$new_total = $total + $tax_total
```

Also, what do you mean your calculations are working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't initiate the variables `$percent10` and `$percent4`

try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 );
function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
    // Get order total
    $total = $order->get_total();

    $orderproduct = $order->get_items();
    $tax_rate     = WC_Tax::get_rates( $orderproduct );
    $percent10 = 0; // if $tax_rate != "10", will sum zero in $new_total
    $percent4 = 0; // if $tax_rate != "4", will sum zero in $new_total

    if ($tax_rate == "10") {
        $percent10 = $total * $tax_rate; 
    }

    if ( $tax_rate == "4" ){
        $percent4 = $total * $tax_rate;
    }

    ## -- fai check e calcoli -- ##
    $new_total = $total + $percent4 + $percent10; // <== Fake calculation

    // imposta un calcolo nuovo
    $order->set_total( $new_total );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you used the wrong parameter of tax function. You can try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_on_checking', 20, 1 );
function change_total_on_checking( $order ) {
    // Get order total
    $total = $order->get_total();

    $orderproduct = $order->get_items();
    foreach($orderproduct as $product){
        $tax_rates     = WC_Tax::get_rates( $product->get_tax_class() );
        if($tax_rate = $tax_rates[1]['rate']){
            if ($tax_rate   == 10) {
                $percent10[] = $total * $tax_rate; 
            }

            if ($tax_rate  == 4) {
                $percent4[] = $total * $tax_rate;
            }
        }

    }
   /* */

    ## -- fai check e calcoli -- ##
    $new_total = $total + floatval((is_array($percent4))? array_sum($percent4): 0) + floatval((is_array($percent10))? array_sum($percent10): 0); // <== Fake calculation
    // imposta un calcolo nuovo
    $order->set_total( $new_total );
}
```